# How to send Hash code to email for reset password yii2 basic?

Tags: email, yii2, hashcode, reset-password

How can I generate a hashed string within a link and send that link via email to a user so that he or she can reset their password?

Comment: Generate a hash string using `Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generateRandomString(64);` save it in a table with user_id, then send email with the hashcode as query string param. You will be able to identify user using that hash and let user change password. Once password changed remove the hashcode from table.

Comment: The flow is very well documented in Advanced template. Please check and follow that flow which is implemented in advanced template...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ForgotForm.php

```
public function sendEmail() {
    $token = substr(base64_encode(sha1(mt_rand())), 0, 64);
    $model = LoginUser::find()->where(['email' => $this->email])->one();
    $model->setAttributes(['token' => $token]);
    if ($model->save()) {
        $mail = Yii::$app->mailer->compose('redirect', ['model' => $model])
                ->setFrom('rosensoul@gmail.com')
                ->setTo($model->email);
        var_dump($mail);
    }
}
```

In redirect.php (in mail folder)

```
<div> <p> Please use this link to reset your password : <?= Url::to(["/site/reset", 'token' => $model->token], TRUE); ?> </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate unique or hashed value from this function

> md5(uniqid(rand(), true));

Save this value in database (field like **key** in user table).
Generate a url with the unique value which we have created and mail to the user.

when the user click on that link get the parameter from the link and check with the value which is saved in the database.

Comment: I use $token = substr(base64_encode(sha1(mt_rand())), 0, 64); for the hash code, but need some code help for the sending email and check it to the database